# jQuery bind click to data attribute instead of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, can I bind a click event to a `data` handle instead of a `class`? I'm not sure how to word it, but this is what I'm trying to do...

```
<a data-user="jason">

$(data-user).click(function() { //This is just for example
```

Right now, I have it this way, but it's causing a lot of problems with other things. Can I use data instead of a class?

```
<a class="user">

$(".user").click(function() { //This is just for example
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('a[data-user="jason"]').click(function() { .... }
```

Updated after OP's comment.

```
$('[data-user]').click(function() { .... }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use only the `data-user`? I don't need the name of the user, since they'll be several.

Comment: @jmenezes yeah `$('[data-user]')`

Comment: Thanks, I never knew this was possible. Saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('a[data-user]').click(function() {});
```